# Conditional grouping and summarizing data frame in [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
                 time = c(3.1,3.2,6.5,12.3, 3.2, 3.4), 
                 intensity = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
```

```
|ID | time| intensity|
|:--|----:|---------:|
|A  |  3.1|        10|
|A  |  3.2|        20|
|B  |  6.5|        30|
|B  | 12.3|        40|
|C  |  3.2|        50|
|C  |  3.4|        60|
```

I would like to aggregate values (sum intensities) by ID *only* when time difference is less than, i.e. 0.3. First I calculated this time difference:

```
df.2 <- df %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(time.diff = max(time) - min(time))
```

...resulting in:

```
|ID | time| intensity| time.diff|
|:--|----:|---------:|---------:|
|A  |  3.1|        10|       0.1|
|A  |  3.2|        20|       0.1|
|B  |  6.5|        30|       5.8|
|B  | 12.3|        40|       5.8|
|C  |  3.2|        50|       0.2|
|C  |  3.4|        60|       0.2|
```

Just to be clear, what I would like to get as an output would be:

```
|ID | time| intensity| time.diff|
|:--|----:|---------:|---------:|
|A  | 3.15|        30|       0.1|
|B  |  6.5|        30|       5.8|
|B  | 12.3|        40|       5.8|
|C  |  3.3|       110|       0.2|
```

where time now is an average of the integrated observations, and intensity is the sum of them. The ID "B" keeps two observations, since its time difference is bigger than 0.3. I have tried with dplyr, but *summarise* will always drop one of the observations of "B", and I want to keep them, and I don't know how to do a *conditional* _group_by_.

I thank you for any idea!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df)[, time.diff := max(time)-min(time), ID][
   time.diff <= 0.3, c('time', 'intensity') := list(mean(time),
        sum(intensity)), ID]) 
#    ID  time intensity time.diff
#1:  A  3.15        30       0.1
#2:  B  6.50        30       5.8
#3:  B 12.30        40       5.8
#4:  C  3.30       110       0.2
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(time.diff=max(time)-min(time), indx=all(time.diff<=0.3),
         intensity=ifelse(indx, sum(intensity), intensity),
         time=ifelse(indx, mean(time), time)) %>% 
   filter(!indx|row_number()==1) %>%
   select(-indx)
 #  ID  time intensity time.diff
 #1  A  3.15        30       0.1
 #2  B  6.50        30       5.8
 #3  B 12.30        40       5.8
 #4  C  3.30       110       0.2
```

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  Corrected the output.  Thanks again for the comments.

Comment: @Arun Yes, it fits better as a separate answer

Comment: @Arun and acrun, both of your solutions are great! I think I would use the _dplyr_ solution, since I am more used to it -- usually I find it more readable, but in this case I must say the _data.table_ solution looks more straightforward than the _dplyr_ one. Thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 3):

Another variation of `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(df)[, time.diff := max(time) - min(time), by = ID
        ][, if (time.diff <= 0.3) 
                .(time = mean(time), intensity = sum(intensity))
            else .SD, by = .(ID, time.diff)]
#    ID time.diff  time intensity
# 1:  A       0.1  3.15        30
# 2:  B       5.8  6.50        30
# 3:  B       5.8 12.30        40
# 4:  C       0.2  3.30       110
```

Comment: `could not find function "."` do I need to upgrade my data.table?

Comment: Oops.. replace it with `list()` instead of `.()` for now.. It's implemented in `v1.9.5+`.. Or install the development version of data.table from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 1):

```
# get time.diff
df$time.diff <- ave(x = df$time,df$ID,FUN = function(x){max(x)-min(x)})

# new split variable to use with ID
df$cut <- cumsum(df$time.diff > .3)

# aggregate everything you need and ignore the cut variable
require(plyr)
ddply(df,c('cut','ID'),summarize,
      time = mean(time),
      intensity = sum(intensity),
      time.diff = mean(time.diff))[2:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT ID, AVG(time) time, SUM(intensity) intensity, (MAX(time)-MIN(time)) dif FROM df 
         GROUP BY ID 
         HAVING (MAX(time)-MIN(time))<0.3
         UNION
         SELECT ID, df.time, df.intensity, df2.dif
         FROM (SELECT ID, AVG(time) time, SUM(intensity) intensity, (MAX(time)-MIN(time)) dif
         FROM df 
         GROUP BY ID 
         HAVING (MAX(time)-MIN(time))>0.3) as df2
         LEFT JOIN df USING (ID)')
```

Output:

```
  ID  time intensity dif
1  A  3.15        30 0.1
2  B  6.50        30 5.8
3  B 12.30        40 5.8
4  C  3.30       110 0.2
```